# StructureMap 2.6 - How to do this in configuration file

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap, ioc-container

Here is the c# code:

```
var server = ******* some internal logic to determine server name ****
var username = ******* some internal logic to determine user name ****
var password = ******* some internal logic to determine password ****

ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{                                            
 x.For<IService<bool>>().Add<Service>()
.Ctor<string>("server").Is(server)
.Ctor<string>("username").Is(username)
.Ctor<string>("password").Is(password)
}
```

This works great but I would like to move this to configuration file as I don't want to reference to concerete type directly in my code.

There isn't much documentation about 2.6. I couldn't find how to handle this in configuration.

Ideally I would like to inject the server, username, and password paramenters in to ObjectFactory and some how use these parameters in the configuration.

(PS: It doesn't necessary need to be with StructureMap any IAC container that can support this scenario will be welcome.)

Thanks

Comment: If you move the mapping to a configuration xml file you will lose refactoring support.  Are you ok with that?

Comment: Yes, that's okay. Although it is not ideal. We have a requirement to be able to change the implementation without recompiling the code.

Comment: Also I forget to tell, this Service object is part of the tree, so I can't do ObjectFactory.GetInstance. StructureMap resolving it automatically.

Comment: I don't understand, what concrete type do you not want to reference and why not?

Comment: If I do the configuration in C# code as in my example, I need to add the assembly that "Service" class belongs to as a reference to my project. I don't want to do that because in the future there'll be other implementations of the same IService interface and I would like to change it without recompiling the code. If the structuremap configuration is in App.Config I can easily replace the Service implementation with another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this type of case would be to introduce a new type to provide the primitive constructor args, and register that in code.  Then you can register the service, and that new type can be auto wired by the container.  This also allows you to move the logic to get the server, username and password into this new object and out of the container configuration.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your reply. I've just implemented the same way you described and yes it looks much cleaner. But at the end I've moved to CastleWindsor as its documentation is much more complete. I really struggled with StructureMap's documentation and there is not much help aspecially for xml configuration, looks like lots of people are configuring it by code (which makes sense if you don't have specific requirements). Thanks Again.